# How do I adjust livepatch schedule?

Tags: canonical-livepatch

Livepatch in 18.04LTS seems to run every hour by default, and its just clogging up my logs with junk.

How do I tune the schedule, to something reasonable, perhaps once per day?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the schedule to e.g. every 6 hours by:

```
sudo canonical-livepatch config check-interval=360
```

Replace `360` with however many minutes you want in between each check. Not sure what's the maximum value it accepts.

Comment: I get "sh: 1: canonical-livepatch: not found", but my syslog shows:

    Mar 21 14:48:41 [servername] canonical-livepatch[1002]: No payload available.
    Mar 21 14:48:41 [servername] canonical-livepatch[1002]: No updates available at this time.
    Mar 21 14:48:41 [servername] canonical-livepatch[1002]: Updated last-check.
    Mar 21 14:48:41 [servername] canonical-livepatch[1002]: Checking with livepatch service.
    Mar 21 14:48:41 [servername] canonical-livepatch[1002]: Client.Check

So I must have some kind of path issue.  "find" is not able to locate it.

Comment: Did you follow all that's on https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch including `sudo snap install canonical-livepatch`?

Comment: No.  This is a base 18.04LTS install.  Apparently livepatch by default gets some kind of partial install?